# Given two relations $R$ of order and $S$ of equivalence look for proposition that is impossible

Tags: relations, order-theory

> Let $R$ and $S$ be two distinct relations defined on a set $A$ such
>   that $R$ is of order and $S$ is of equivalence. Indicate which of the
>   following statements is impossible to occur:
>
> 1. $R\subseteq S$.
> 2. $|R|>|S|$.
> 3. $R\cup S$ is of order.
> 4. $R\cap S$ is not of order.

---

I have no idea how to find the impossible statement.

I tried finding some examples of relations $R$ and $S$ to prove the impossibility, but then I realized that I can take other examples where the statement is true.

Comment: What do "is of order" and "is of equivalence" mean?

Comment: If you, for instance, can find a _single_ example where $R\subseteq S$, then that means it is possible, so 1. is not the answer. If you try a couple of different ordering relations and equivalence relations, and use that to rule out a couple of the options, whichever are left are more likely to necessarily be impossible. See if you can prove that they are. And if you're stuck, come back here and tell us exactly what you've tried, and where you got stuck, and we will be better equipped to give you help that will _help you_.

Comment: @JohnDouma [Partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) and [Equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equality is both an order relation and an equivalence, so (1) can occur.
Equality is contained in any order relation, so (2) can occur too.
Since equality is of both types, taking $R$ and $S$ to be equality, their union is still equality, an order relation, so (3) can occur.

Now, if $R$ is an order relation and $S$ an equivalence, they are both reflexive and transitive, and so $R \cap S$ is reflexive and transitive too.
Can you prove that $R \cap S$ is still anti-symmetric?
If so, then $R\cap S$ is an order relation, and so it can't happen that $R\cap S$ is not an order relation, that is (4) cannot occur.